# Is there an API for Mozilla for updating signed addons?

Tags: firefox-addon, multipartform-data, firefox-addon-webextensions, pycurl

I have a signed addon that I use personally but would like to experiment with making it distributable via AMO. I have already uploaded the initial version through the Developer Hub, and I'm now hoping to be able to include an automated release through a CI pipeline.

I've been investigating how to do this for a while now, having found [this article](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/11/20/signing-api-now-available/) and [API doc](http://addons-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html) but haven't had much luck. I'm definitely able to connect with my JWT properly, as I get either a 301 (I assume this is because the API described in the article has been changed in the last two years) but then a 400 when I follow the redirects.

Every request returns *Missing "upload" key in multipart file data.* I believe this is to do with the endpoint being a PUT but expecting a multipart form (all my research points to this being supported by POST only). I've tried several different approaches, both with cURL and with various Python libraries - including PyCurl to try and use the multipart in a POST request and override only the method to PUT - but just don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I haven't been able to find any recent documentation on this, as the older articles imply it's a deprecated API but the newer docs don't seem to have the answers I'm looking for. Issues like [this one](https://github.com/mozilla/addons-server/issues/5693) suggest it's still possible, and I've seen mention of web-ext but I think I'm just missing how to put the pieces together.

My request is:

```
    curl -XPUT https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/{myId}/versions/0.2 -F 'upload=../toolbox.api' -H 'Authorization: JWT <myToken>' -v -L
```

Has anyone tried to do this and have any advice on how to move forward? Or conversely know that it's definitely *not* possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the node.js based command [web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) to sign extensions from command line.

Like with the curl approach you obtain the issuer/secret, then use those as given arguments or environment variables:

```
web-ext sign --api-key=$AMO_JWT_ISSUER --api-secret=$AMO_JWT_SECRET
```

If you need to [use a proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference#--api-proxy):

```
web-ext sign --api-key=... --api-secret=... --api-proxy=https://yourproxy:6000
```

Please see the linked article for [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference) (and its other features).

Comment: I'd seen this extension but wasn't sure how to use it (plus I figured how hard could it be to convert a cURL request to Python...). These links were really helpful though and I was surprised at how easy it was to setup and use. Works like a charm! Thanks!